# Why is the constness of struct pNext fields inconsistent?

Tags: vulkan

Structs defined by the Vulkan API use the `sType` and `pNext` members to enable assembling chains of structs. But some structs (e.g., `VkDeviceCreateInfo`) declare `pNext` as `const void*` and other structs (e.g., `VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures2`) declare it only as `void*`. Is there any reason for the inconsistency? I couldn't find any mention in the spec of an intentional meaning behind the difference in constness, or any discussion of this online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of those structs is an input; the other is an output. `VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures2`, and all of the structs in its `pNext` linked list are for the API to write data into which you will read. It's not `const` because it will be modified.

This is not "inconsistency"; it's `const`-correctness.

Comment: I see. It didn't occur to me to characterize the different `pNext`-bearing structs as "input" or "output" because some, including `VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures2`, are used as either depending on the API call (for that struct, querying features vs. device creation).